# Adding text to a PDF

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate a PDF document. I was able to create and add a table. Now I'd like to add some normal text to the PDF. How do I do that? I looked online and they suggested using chunks but it's not working:

```
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("A chunk represents an isolated string. ");
```

This is how I was adding the table:

```
private byte[] CreatePDFFile(StudentJournalAdd studentjournal, SearchResult<JournalAttendanceStatus> StatusList, string studentName)
{
    var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12);
    var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
    string Details = string.Empty;
    int icount = 0;
    bool bflag = false;

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.TotalWidth = 550f;
    table.LockedWidth = true;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 10f, 20f, 10f };
    table.SetWidths(widths);
    table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

    table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
    table.SpacingAfter = 30f;
    table.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = 2f;
    table.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 2f;

    //PdfPCell cellHeading = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("AdminNo - " + studentjournal.StudentJournaldtls.AdminNo + " (WeekNo) - " + studentjournal.StudentJournaldtls.WeekNo + "\n\n", boldFont));
    PdfPCell cellHeading = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Temasek Polytechnic - Student Internship Programme Journal\n\n " + studentName + " (" + studentjournal.StudentJournaldtls.AdminNo + ")\n\n Week No: " + studentjournal.StudentJournaldtls.WeekNo + "\n\n" + "DAILY/WEEKLY SUMMARY OF TASKS" + "\n\n", boldFont));

    cellHeading.Colspan = 3;
    cellHeading.Rowspan = 2;
    cellHeading.Border = 0;
    cellHeading.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    cellHeading.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    table.AddCell(cellHeading);

    PdfPCell cell0 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Day", boldFont));
    cell0.PaddingBottom = 10f;
    cell0.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell0.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table.AddCell(cell0);

    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Task Assigned", boldFont));
    cell1.PaddingBottom = 10f;
    cell1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table.AddCell(cell1);

    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Attendance", boldFont));
    cell2.PaddingBottom = 10f;
    cell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table.AddCell(cell2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`PdfPTable` and `Chunk` are only two elements that can be added to a `Document` in iTextSharp. Please take a look at [the official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com). For instance, if you browse to the examples of the "iText in Action - Second Edition" book, you'll find [a couple of hundreds of examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-5-examples/itext-action-second-edition). At the bottom of each example page, you find links to the C# version of each example. For instance:

```
// step 1
using (Document document = new Document()) {
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
    // step 3
    document.Open();
    // step 4
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!")); 
}
```

In this simple Hello World example, we add a `Paragraph`. That already answers your question: "How do I add some normal text to a PDF?"

In [chapter 2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-2), you'll discover other elements such as `Anchor`, `List` (and `ListItem`), and so on.

However, it seems that you are new at using iText. In that case, why don't you start with the newest iText version? We have just rewritten iText from scratch, and we are introducing a completely new API.

You can find a more elaborate overview of the new classes in the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the examples from *iText in Action - Second Edition* [here on the itextpdf site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-5-examples/itext-action-second-edition).

At first you see the Java / iText versions of the samples but at the end of the respective page you'll also find links to C# / iTextSharp versions.

For example, on the page of the [chapter 1 examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1) you'll find a link to this simple Hello World program which *adds some normal text to the PDF*:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace kuujinbo.iTextInAction2Ed.Chapter01 {
  public class HelloWorld : IWriter {
// ===========================================================================
    public void Write(Stream stream) {
      // step 1
      using (Document document = new Document()) {
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        // step 3
        document.Open();
        // step 4
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!")); 
      }          
    }
// ===========================================================================
  }
}
```

*([HelloWorld.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/blob/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter01/HelloWorld.cs))*

---

In short, therefore,

> Now i would like to add some normal text to the PDF. How do i do that?

You simply create a `Paragraph` and add it to your `Document` instance.

---

That been said, as you are new to iText anyways, why don't you start using the current iText 7 for .Net?

Comment: We almost answered simultaneously ;-)